# form type calendar and editor

Tags: joomla2.5

I have in my component on frontend two field calendar and editor. I have problem with both, this is my files:

```
<field name="description"
type="editor"
label="COM_BETTING_FIELD_DESC_LABEL"
description = "COM_BETTING_FIELD_DESC_DESC"
class="inputbox"
filter="safehtml"
buttons="false"
/>

<field name="start_data" 
type="calendar"    
label="Select a date" 
description="" 
format="%d-%m-%Y" />
```

and my problem is in calendar dont display popup window to choice data.
and in editor I need change under field to use editor not, default is only textarea.
I try add this but not work. editor="desired" when I use editor="none" It work and I have only textarea without option change for editor.

Comment: Check if there are any javascript errors on the page, since the functionality of both of these items require javascript.

Comment: how I can check this?

Comment: In chrome, right click the page and click inspect element. Click the console button in the lower left corner and see if there is anything with a red x next to it.

Comment: I have this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { dodawanie-beta:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input dodawanie-beta:1
GET http://localhost/joomla//plugins/system/plg_ztools/plg_ztools/assets/images/loading.gif 404 (Not Found) dodawanie-beta:1